# Update data with select2

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I'm using select2.

I'm looking for a way to update my data array.

```
$('#add-users').select2({
    theme: 'bootstrap4',
    placeholder: 'Invite someone',
    allowClear: true,
    tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
    data: users
});
```

On this one, I just need to update data from the select2 add-users. (Removing or adding elements that I want in it).

Comment: Can you post your current code to try to achieve this, with an explanation of what is not working?

Comment: The issue is that I don't know how to just update my data property.
I just want to refresh it by removing or adding items from the actual data array (data property).

Comment: If you have no code, then your request is more 'write some code for me' than 'I need help with this specific problem'. I'd recommend searching for updating elements via JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can't update select2
You have to destroy it with

```
$('#myselect').empty().trigger('change');
```

or

```
$('#myselect').select2('destroy').trigger('change');
```

And then recreate it with your data